# Android Studio Blue Square on Directory

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I just imported a project from Eclipse into Android Studio to try it out. I'm seeing some directories that have a little blue square in the lower right corner, and some directories that are blue instead of orange-ish. Does that mean something (I assume it does), and if so, what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue squares: these are module roots. Equivalent of projects in Eclipse.
Blue directories: these are source roots within a module.

You can explore and configure the module structure and the source directories in more detail from *Project Structure* (Ctrl-Shift-Alt-S).

For more information, take a look at the [Project Tool Window help topic](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html)

Comment: You can't yet configure source roots in a Gradle-based project, which this is. That's yet to be implemented; in the meantime if you need to adjust source directories, you have to edit `build.gradle` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of gradle, you could configure sourceSets easily:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
}
```

and here ***srcDirs*** takes an array of path, which allows you to add multiple directories as source sets, e.g.:

```
main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java']
```

Then you'll have two blueish directories in your Android Studio Project View.